# Variance Decomposition in Generalized Linear Models

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I'm using a generalized linear model (with a Negative Binomial distribution for observed variables) to model my data. I was wondering whether using the partial coefficient of determination is appropriate for variance decomposition in a glm? In other words, I want to calculate the proportion of variance (in the observed data) explained by each covariate in the model. I basically want to know whether it would be a good measure, and also, is there a way I can achieve equivalent information by handling deviances?
To be more specific, I'm using the packaged DESeq2 in R to handle my data. 
I'd appreciate any comments.